# How to set up the master-detail view in the Ionic Lab starter project “Sidemenu”?

Tags: javascript, ios, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic Lab to learn the basics. I have the starter template "Sidemenu", which is some sort of almost-functioning music app. It mainly shows off the side menu – which works fine, but slightly annoyingly the master-detail pattern included in the Playlist part of the app seems only partly set up. The master (list) view uses an array of data, but the detail view is just using a generic hardcoded bit of HTML. It must be very easy to go one step further and have both the master and detail views reading from the same array, displaying different data in the different templates (which have been setup already, as has the controller for the detail view – but it's empty).. but I'm struggling to work out what the correct approach is.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Listing view:

```
<ion-view view-title="Playlists">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="playlist in playlists" href="#/app/playlists/{{playlist.id}}">
        {{playlist.title}} – 
        {{playlist.content}}
        <p>{{playlist.id}}</p>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Detail view:

```
<ion-view view-title="Playlist">
  <ion-content>
    <h1>Playlist</h1>
    <ion-item class="card">
        <div class="item item-text-wrap">
            {{playlist.title}}
            Bar
        </div>
        <div class="item item-text-wrap">    
            Foo
            {{playlist.content}}
        </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

app.js:

```
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

   //... some other states here

    .state('app.playlists', {
      url: '/playlists',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/playlists.html',
          controller: 'PlaylistsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('app.single', {
    url: '/playlists/:playlistId',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/playlist.html',
        controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/playlists');
});
```

controllers.js

```
    .controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.playlists = [
    {
        content: 'Integer legentibus erat a ante historiarum dapibus.',
        title: 'Reggae',
        id: 1 
    },
    { 
        content: 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus.',
        title: 'Chill',
        id: 2 
    }
  ];
})

.controller('PlaylistCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    // empty, as it is by default, but I've tried adding data here and nothing happens
});
```

The data in the detail view does not load. I guess I need to set something else up?

Any help – even if it's just something I should read about myself, would be much appreciated.

controllers.js

Answer (score 1):

The ID value passed in will be available in $stateParams. If you console.dir it, you will see it. I believe the value will be playlistId. Given that the data is fake (see the list above), your code could do something like this:

```
$scope.playlists = [
{
    content: 'Integer legentibus erat a ante historiarum dapibus.',
    title: 'Reggae',
    id: 1 
},
{ 
    content: 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus.',
    title: 'Chill',
    id: 2 
}
];
$scope.selected = $scope.playlists[$stateParams.playlistId-1];
```

Since the IDs (1 and 2) match the array items, you can get the selected value by just using the array index. Obviously a real app would not duplicate the data like this and use a service, but if you just want to get this running, it will give you a leg up.

I used $scope.selected as the variable, so in the view, use {{selected.title}} for example.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be clear, could you explain exactly what you mean by "Obviously a real app would not duplicate the data like this and use a service" – what data is duplicated here?

Comment: In the controller, you have an array of data defined in PlaylistsCtrl and repeated in PlaylistCtrl. That's "Bad" - pretty much any time you duplicate code it is bad. But as I said - as a quick fix just to see things working, it gets things done. I do bad crap all the time - just recognize why. ;)

Comment: Yes, I see. Interestingly this duplication was already in the starter project from Ionic.. and seemed to me to be a bit weird. I think they could easily make some improvements.. as someone with a non-computer science background I find the best way to learn is from simple well-made examples, but this one had me a bit confused. Hopefully I will find it easier from here. Thanks so much for your help, I will try out what you've suggested. All the best.